# MySQL JOIN is fast, but selecting column is slow

Tags: mysql, index, join

My `logs` table has half a million rows.  Each row has an indexed `log_level_id` column pointing to table `log_levels` (with only 5 rows).  On `log_levels`, `id` is an auto-increment primary key and `label` has no index.

The super simple query below runs fast on MySQL 5.5 but suddenly screeches to a grinding halt on MySQL 5.7 (e.g. less than 1/4 a second to over 10 minutes):

```
SELECT logs.id ,log_levels.label
    FROM logs 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN log_levels ON log_levels.id = logs.log_level_id
```

Why would the lack of index on `log_levels.label` cause this slowdown? Why would I need to place an index on this column when I'm not referencing the column in `WHERE` or `ORDER`?

Without an index on `label`, `EXPLAIN` shows:

```
table: log_levels
type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
key: ??? shouldn't this resolve to PRIMARY?
key_len:
ref: 
rows: 5
Extra: Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

If I add an index on `log_levels.label`, EXPLAIN changes to:

```
table: log_levels
type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
key: PRIMARY
key_len:1
ref: logs.log_level_id
rows: 1
Extra:
```

I've never experienced a difference in query speed based on whether there's an index on a select column (`label`) that does not appear in `WHERE` or `ORDER` clauses.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Table with 5 rows will be loaded in memory completely regardless of index presence .

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: The query return 0.5M rows; is that what you are timing?

Comment: Is the Query cache turned on?  How long does it take on 5.5 to do `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`?

Comment: Please show us the other 'line' of the `EXPLAIN`.